# Filter to identify outliers in Python

Tags: python, boxplot, outliers

I'm trying to remove outliers falling in 2 ranges, but keep receiving errors. I've tried with the Boolean & and | characters, np.logical_or and np.logical_and, with a .any(), or .all() as well, to no avail. Could someone please advise what I'm doing wrong here? This is the boxplot that shows the outliers:
[image]

and here's the code I'm trying to use to filter out the outliers:
[image]

Thanks in advance for feedback.

Comment: Sharing images is one (bad) thing, sharing incomplete images is another

Comment: The screenshot doesn't show the last part of the error message which actually tells you what's wrong

Comment: Sorry, just updated with the complete error. Thanks.

Comment: Would this work? Compute `rm_filter = (df['RM'] >=7.75) | (df['RM'] <=4.75)`. Now, `rm_filter` is a `pd.Series` object with only `True` or `False` values. Now, you can do `df[rm_filter]` to get a dataframe with only the outliers. So, basically, use `|` instead of `or` and don't index `df` by your filter twice.

Comment: @Ankur, thank you! This totally worked! Now I'm trying to remove the outliers identified, but running into issues when I try:

df_rm_outlier_rem = df.drop(df[rm_filter],axis=0,inplace=True)

It's throwing a KeyError about not finding the columns in the axis. Any further suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'd love to mark your suggestion as the answer, but don't see how to do it to your comment. If you post your comment as an answer, I think that would work then. Thanks in advance!

Comment: df_rm_outlier_rem = df.drop(df[rm_filter],axis=0,inplace=True) says key error probably because you want to use axis = 1

Comment: @YevGuyduy, thank you for your pointer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the comments, you can compute the bitmask `rm_filter` like so:

```
rm_filter = (df['RM'] >=7.75) | (df['RM'] <=4.75)
```

and should be able to remove those records like:

```
df_rm_outlier_rem = df[~rm_filter]
```

where the tilde ~ negates the filter.

Comment: thank you.....this was very helpful!